# Data Frame Error: UndefinedVariableError: name is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, csv, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I'm working in a jupyter notebook and am trying to create objects for two different answers in a column: Yes and No; in order to see the similarities between all of the 'yes' responses and the same for the 'no' responses as well.

When I use the following code, i get an error that states: UndefinedVariableError: name 'No' is not defined

```
df_yes=df.query('No-show == \"Yes\"')
df_no=df.query('No-show == \"No\"')
```

Since the same error occurs even when I'm only including the df_yes, then I figured it has to have something to do with the column name "No-show." So I tried it with different columns and sure enough, it works.

So can someone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong with with this code block so I won't do it again? Thanks!

Comment: You are attempting to take the column `No` and subtract the column `show` from it.  I don't know if there's any way to escape a column name that has invalid characters in it; a simpler solution would be to name the column more reasonably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe this example:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'col1': ['Yes','No'], 'col2': ['No','No']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df.query('col1 == \"Yes\"')
  col1 col2
0  Yes   No
>>> df.query('col2 == \"Yes\"')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
>>>
```

Everything seems to work as expected. But, if I change `col1` and `col2` to `col-1` and `col-2`, respectively:

```
>>> d = {'col-1': ['Yes','No'], 'col-2': ['No','No']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df.query('col-1 == \"Yes\"')
...
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'col' is not defined
```

As you can see, the problem is the minus (`-`) you use in your column name. As a matter of fact, you were even more unlucky because `No` in your error message refers to `No-show` and not to the value `No` of your columns.

So, the best solution (and best practice in general) is to name your columns differently (think of them as variables; you can not have a minus in the name of a variable, at least in Python). For example, `No_show`. If this data frame is not created by you (e.g. you read your data from a `csv` file), it 's a common practice to [rename columns appropriately](https://medium.com/@chaimgluck1/working-with-pandas-fixing-messy-column-names-42a54a6659cd).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to rename the column and now it works!

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need to escape `"` since your query string is in `'` (that is a very handy feature of Python), i.e. you can write `df.query('col1 == "Yes"')` instead of `df.query('col1 == \"Yes\"')`.